# Is it possible to use .css() to change property

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Actually i'm studying jQuery and using Twitter BootStrap to try to develop a WP template.
What I would like to achieve is the possibility to change a css property using jquery.

This is what I would like to achieve

From this:

```
margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
```

To this:

```
margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
```

As you can see I would like to keep the value but change the property.

This is the 'original' css part:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-height: 30px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elems = $('.row-fluid [class*="span"]');

elems.css({
    marginRight : elems.css('margin-left'), // gets the margin from the first element
    marginLeft  : 0
});
```

Note that `css()` sets the value for all elements in the collection, but gets the value from the first element in the collection.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to adjust the `margin-left` and `margin-right` values accordingly.

```
$('.row-fluid [class*="span"]').css({
    'margin-left':'0',
    'margin-right':'2.564102564102564%'
});
```

Comment: Your solution is good but it could be done also via CSS, I think that the ones proposed by user2505347 or @adeneo will be simpler to implement as they store the value as a variable and then 'switch' the value betwen the properties.
So.. don't be angry with me but I think that I'll choose Adeneo's as correct answer

Comment: True. I was really trying to demonstrate how it's done, as the OP doesn't seem to know how to use the CSS function. For someone of that level, having a so many calls to a non-understood function could be confusing. Also, switching between the use of the variable as an array and as a single object is a concept I wasnt sure of they would get. 6 of one, half dozen of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in two steps. Remove the left margin, then add the right margin:

```
$('.row-fluid [class*="span"]').css('margin-left', 0);
$('.row-fluid [class*="span"]').css('margin-right', '2.564102564102564%');
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you calling out for the selector twice? That forces jQuery to do twice the work when locating then element(s)

Comment: FYI: [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) can take an object specifying multiple properties to change at once.

Comment: You guys are both right... Upvoting your answer, @Dutchie432! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just read the property, save its value, remove the property and add the new property with the saved value.

```
var tmp = $('.row-fluid [class*="span"]').css('margin-left');
$('.row-fluid [class*="span"]').css({'margin-left': 0, 'margin-right': tmp});
```

Comment: Again, calling out for the selector twice forces jQuery to do twice the work when locating then element(s)